# When do we need to add frameworks to a Xcode project?

Tags: objective-c, clang, clang++

I am confused by this. When I declare my view controller as `.m` file,

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <Speech/Speech.h>
```

These two lines in `ViewController.h` won't cause linking issue. I didn't add any frameworks to my Xcode project.

But when I change it to `.mm` file because I need to use a **C++** library, I got linking issue for the AVFoundation library, and I need to manually add it to my project `General -> Link Frameworks and Libraries`. Why? Why doesn't this issue appear when I am compiling an `.m` file?